# GUI doesn't display the background i set for it(compiles)

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to create a GUI for a game I am trying to make, the game is irrelevant.

what this should do according to me is show me a GUI, with a frame, with a picture, however, just the frame displays, the image is nowhere to be found :(

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong?
Thank you for your time!

```
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
     import javax.swing.JPanel;
     import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
     import javax.swing.JLabel;
     import javax.swing.*;
     import java.awt.BorderLayout;
     import java.awt.*;

     public class Graph
     {
     int maxX,maxY;
     private JFrame frame;

     Graph()
     {
     Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
     maxX = screenSize.width;
     maxY = screenSize.height;
     frame = new JFrame("My Application");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setSize(maxX, maxY);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
     JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
     panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     frame.setVisible(true);




    }


    public String g()
    {

    return this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().replaceAll("´        20", " ");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Graph g = new Graph();
        }
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why extend JFrame when you are just creating a JFrame inside of it anyway? Also, I think the problem lies with the order you are doing things e.g. you are building/displaying the frame, _then_ adding components.

Comment: Also realized and deleted that now too, I'll edit, result is the same though, i'l look into that

Comment: Tried it, same result, but perhaps i just dont quite get what you are saying , could you show example?

Comment: Post your new edited version of your code as an edit to your question. As a simple example, `frame.setVisible()` should probably be the very last thing you call after adding all your components and packing the frame.

Comment: You can edit it again and again. You said you changed the order of adding components vs building/displaying your frame. Show that.

Comment: You are still setting up the frame before adding any of your components e.g. you call `InitUI` before adding your JPanel.

Comment: Oooh i see, still doesn't work though

Comment: Once again, you built the frame _then_ added your panel.

Comment: trying, if it doesnt work i'l respond again

Comment: I also need to ask, where is your `main()` method? This isn't going to run at all without a `main()`. See my posted answer and see if you have questions/problems after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should show you the correct order in which to perform the operations you want. Also, the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method is the way you should start a swing application. This uses the EDT which you can read about [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Another note is that you set the size of the frame, but when it displays it will be much smaller. That is because you have used `frame.pack()` which will make sure that only the space you really need is used up.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Graph {
    JFrame frame;

    public Graph() {
        frame = new JFrame("My Application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1366,770);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("SomeLabel");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Graph g = new Graph();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. I just try to walk through the problem first rather than go straight to posting an answer. I find it helps people understand/learn a bit better.

Comment: argh still doesn't work... but i have the right setup now though, i'l edit

Comment: Yes, please edit your question with your now updated code so I can check it out. What I have posted runs fine on 2 different machines I have here.

Comment: It works, like it did before, just... no background ;)

Comment: Are you sure that java is recognizing the correct filepath to your image?

Comment: well, i have been messing around with swing for a couple of days now, every time I use images i place them in the folder where the bluej file is, so path should be correct :s

Comment: I'm going to see if another user on here (@HovercraftFullOfEels) might be willing to take a peek at it for you. He is really great with swing, and I unfortunately am not. I have not used images in swing before so anything I say from here would be pure guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, Appreciate it man :), and thanks for asking that other user too! :)